# devexpress gridcontrol selectedrow binding to textbox text in wpf without using MVVM

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox, gridcontrol, devexpress-wpf

I have a dev express grid control in my user control and want to bind my textbox.text to the selected row of grid control.

I used a `textbox.text = {binding elementname=gridcontrolname path=selecteditem.name` but it didn't work.i'm not using MVVM and my grid control is bind to an observable collection

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml code you put this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=gridcontrolename, Path=SelectedItem.name}"/>
```

Pay attention to upper and lower case. **SelectedItem.Name** is not the same thing as **selecteditem.name**